# Compare two recordset variables gives type mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I have a bound form with several subforms. some of these subforms can 0 or more records, others have 1 or more.
The form is always open in read-only and on it there are an "edit" and a "close" button.
When the user clicks on the edit button I save the content of the current record togehter with all records of the subforms so that when he/she clicks on the close button I can ask wether to save or not and, if not, discard the changes restoring from saved records.
So far this is the code of the edit button (where `GclnAllCnts` is a global variable of type Dictionary):

```
Private Sub EditLibroBtn_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_EditLibroBtn_Click
    Dim lngID         As Long
    Dim ctlCnt        As Control
    Dim rs            As Recordset
    lngID = Me.ID
    Set GclnAllCnts = New Dictionary
    GclnAllCnts.Add Me.Name, Me.RecordsetClone
    For Each ctlCnt In Me.Controls
        If (ctlCnt.ControlType = acSubform) Then
            Set rs = ctlCnt.Form.RecordsetClone
            If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
                GclnAllCnts.Add ctlCnt.Name, ctlCnt.Form.RecordsetClone
            Else
                GclnAllCnts.Add ctlCnt.Name, Null
            End If
        End If
    Next
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm GCstMainFrmName, , , "ID = " & lngID, acFormEdit, acDialog

Exit_EditLibroBtn_Click:
    Set ctlCnt = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_EditLibroBtn_Click:
    MsgBox err.Description & vbNewLine & "Error number: " & err.Number, vbCritical, "Errore"
    Resume Exit_EditLibroBtn_Click
End Sub
```

And this is the code of the close button:

```
Private Sub ChiudiBtn_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_ChiudiBtn_Click
    Dim intBoxAwr   As Integer
    Dim stSQL       As String
    Dim vKey        As Variant
    Dim ctlCnt      As Control
    Dim clnAllCnts  As Dictionary
    Dim bSaveNeeded As Boolean
    bSaveNeeded = False
    If (Me.AllowEdits And Me.ID <> "" And Not IsNull(Me.ID)) Then
        Set clnAllCnts = New Dictionary
        clnAllCnts.Add Me.Name, Me.RecordsetClone
        For Each ctlCnt In Me.Controls
            If (ctlCnt.ControlType = acSubform) Then
                Set rs = ctlCnt.Form.RecordsetClone
                If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
                    clnAllCnts.Add ctlCnt.Name, ctlCnt.Form.RecordsetClone
                Else
                    clnAllCnts.Add ctlCnt.Name, Null
                End If
            End If
        Next
       If clnAllCnts.Count <> GclnAllCnts.Count Then
            bSaveNeeded = True
        Else
            For Each vKey In clnAllCnts.keys()
                If Not GclnAllCnts.Exists(vKey) Then
                    bSaveNeeded = True
                    Exit For
                Else
'*********** Next Gives error **********
                    If clnAllCnts.Item(vKey) <> GclnAllCnts.Item(vKey) Then
                        bSaveNeeded = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If bSaveNeeded Then
            intBoxAwr = MsgBox("Salvare le modifiche al libro?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Salvare")
            If intBoxAwr = vbYes Then
        'etc., omitting code
End Sub
```

The error I get is *Type mismatch* (nr. 13) and it is given by the `<>` comparison (I can Debug.print `IsNull(clnAllCnts.Item(vKey))` and `IsNull(GclnAllCnts.Item(vKey))`.
**How can I compare the two recordset variables?**

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two Recordset objects by simply saying `If rst1 <> rst2` could be dicey anyway, because what does that really mean? Such an expression could very well return `True` every time, if `rst1` and `rst2` really *are* different objects (even if they are of the same object Type).

It appears that you are interested in whether the *contents* of the two Recordsets is the same. In that case, I would be inclined to serialize the recordset data and store the resulting `String` instead of storing the `Recordset` object itself.

The following VBA Function may prove helpful in that case. It loops through a recordset object and produces a JSON-like string containing the current recordset data.

(Note that the function may NOT necessarily produce valid JSON. It doesn't escape non-printing characters like `vbCr` and `vbLf`. It doesn't escape backslashes (`\`). It stores all values as either "string" or `null`. In other words, in its current form it is not designed to produce a string that could later be *deserialized*.)

```vbs
Private Function rstSerialize(ByVal rst As DAO.Recordset)
    ' loop through the recordset and generate a JSON-like string
    '     NB: This code will NOT necessarily produce valid JSON!
    '
    Dim s As String, fld As DAO.Field, rowCount As Long, fldCount As Long

    s = "{"
    If Not (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
        rst.MoveFirst
        rowCount = 0
        Do Until rst.EOF
            If rowCount > 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
            End If
            s = s & """row"": {"
            fldCount = 0
            For Each fld In rst.Fields
                If fldCount > 0 Then
                    s = s & ", "
                End If
                s = s & """" & fld.Name & """: " & IIf(IsNull(fld.Value), "null", """" & fld.Value & """")
                fldCount = fldCount + 1
            Next
            s = s & "}"
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    s = s & "}"
    rstSerialize = s
End Function
```

**Data Example:** If the Recordset contained

```
DonorID  Amount
-------  ------
      1      10
      2      20
```

the function would return the string

```
{"row": {"DonorID": "1", "Amount": "10"}, "row": {"DonorID": "2", "Amount": "20"}}
```

**Usage Example:** On a form that contains a subform, a button on the main form could do the following

```vbs
Private Sub Command3_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, originalState As String
    Set rst = Me.MemberDonationsSubform.Form.RecordsetClone
    originalState = rstSerialize(rst)
    rst.MoveFirst
    rst.Edit
    rst!Amount = rst!Amount + 1
    rst.Update
    Debug.Print "(Recordset updated.)"
    If rstSerialize(rst) = originalState Then
        Debug.Print "Recordset does not appear to have changed."
    Else
        Debug.Print "Recordset appears to have changed."
    End If
End Sub
```

which would print the following in the VBA Immediate Window

```
(Recordset updated.)
Recordset appears to have changed.
```